# Show related div based on selected option

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-blade

maybe someone can help me with my problem? All I need is to show div with content (schema of div is always the same actually, but content (id, name etc.) different based on user’s selection. For instance, user choose module 1 and below shows module one, choose module 2 and shows module 2. I presume I can do it with ajax or jQuery, but all I tried doesn't work properly. My logic in view is:

```
   <script>
        function showSmtpType() {
            var selectBox = document.getElementById('type');
            var userInput = selectBox.options[selectBox.selectedIndex].value;
            @foreach($modules as $module)
            if (userInput == "{{ route("module", ['module' => ($module->id)]) }}"){
                document.getElementById('moduleType').style.visibility ='visible';}
            else {
                document.getElementById('moduleType').style.visibility ='hidden';
            }
            return false;
            @endforeach
        }
    </script>
    <main class="main">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="animated fadeIn">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-8">
                                <h4 class="head">Module-setup</h4>
                                <div class="col-md-9 col-xl-6">
                                    <span class="head-2">Module:</span>
                                    <select class="dropdownHeader function" id="type" name="type" onchange="return showSmtpType();">
                                        @foreach($modules as $module)
                                            <option value="{{ route("module", ['module' => ($module->id)]) }}">{{$module->name }}</option>
                                        @endforeach
                                    </select>
                                </div>
    {{--Begin of description--}}
                                <div class="card-custom  bg-primary-2" >
<div class="card-body pb-0">
                                    @foreach($modules as $k=>$item)
                                    @if($k ==0)
                                    <div class="btn-group float-right">
                                        <button class="btn btn-transparent dropdown-toggle p-0" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                            <i class="icon-settings"></i>
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="text-value">
                                        @if($item->enabled == 1)
                                        <input checked name="enabled" type="checkbox" value=""><span class="checkbox">
                                            </span>
                                                 @endif
                                                @if ($item->enabled ==0)
                                                <input  name="enabled" type="checkbox" value=""><span class="checkbox"></span>
                                                        @endif
                                         Enabled </span><br/>
                                                    @if($item->active == 1)
                                        <input checked name="active" type="checkbox" value=""><span class="checkbox">
                                                        </span>
                                                            @endif
                                                            @if($item->active == 0)
                                        <input name="active" type="checkbox" value=""><span class="checkbox">
                                                                    @endif
                                                            Active</span>
                                            @endif
                                                @endforeach
                                    </div>
                                    <div id="moduleType" style="visibility: hidden;">
                                        <span style="margin-right: 40px;">Database:</span>
                                        {!! Form::text('database',isset($module->DB)? $module->DB : old('DB'),['placeholder' =>'Database'])!!}
                                        <br/> <br/>
                                        <span style="margin-right: 75px;">Path:</span>
                                        {!! Form::text('path',isset($module->path)? $module->path : old('PATH'),['placeholder' =>'Path'])!!}
                                        <br/><br/>
                                        <span style="margin-right: 5px;">Friendly name:</span>
                                        {!! Form::text('standardname',isset($module->standardname)? $module->standardname : old('DB'),['placeholder' =>'Friendly name'])!!}
                                        <br/><br/>
                                        <span style="margin-right: 20px;">Icon(20x20):</span>
                                        @if(isset($module->icon))
                                            <li style="list-style: none;" class="textarea-field">
                                                <label>
                                                    <span class="label">Image:</span>
                                                </label>
                                                {{ Html::image(asset('/images/img/icons'.$module->icon->path)) }}
                                                {!! Form::hidden('old_image',$module->icon->path) !!}
                                            </li>
  @endif
                                        <li style="list-style: none;" class="text-field">
                                            <div class="input-prepend">
                                                {!! Form::file('image',['class'=>'filestyle', 'data-buttonText'=>'choose image','data-buttonName'=>'image'])!!}
                                            </div>
                                        </li>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="chart-wrapper mt-3 mx-3" style="height:70px;">
                                    <canvas class="chart" id="card-chart1" height="70"></canvas>
                                </div>
                            </div>
{{--End of div with description of module--}}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </main>
```

Will be very appreciate! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript to solve this problem. You would need to write a function attached to what the user selects, e.g. onSelect, and when the user selects an option, depending on which option it is (you will have to write some logic), it can reveal your functionality which is in a hidden div.

So, hide the form element for answers 1 and 2 in two separate divs. You can set these divs to have the quality:

`display:none`

which will hide them. Once they have selected form element 1 (or 2), reveal the relevant div related to it. You can do this in JavaScript using:

`document.getElementById("formQuestionTwo").style.display = "block";`

PHP is server side so you cannot alter what is on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

The value of the select options shouldn't be a route but rather maybe the module id. Instead of creating many divs based on the modules, You can give the elements in a single div specific ids and use JQuery to target the specific elements and change its content.

```
<select class="dropdownHeader function" id="type" name="type">
@foreach($modules as $module)
 <option value="{{ $module->id }}">{{$module->name }}</option>
@endforeach
</select>


<script>
// Using JQuery
$('#type').change(function() {
 const modules = {!! $modules !!};
 const type = this.val(); // a constant that holds the value of the selected type
 const module = modules[type]; // a constant that holds the module of the selected type

 // here target the div elements and change its content or manipulate it
 // For instance you have a <span id="status"></span> in the div. You can do
 $('#status').html(module.enabled); // this would change the span content to that of the selected type.

 // In vanilla javascript you can do
 document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = module.enabled;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer! I'm newbie in jQuery, so I'm not sure how to do it. How can I target div elements? Something like this?:
<script>
$('#type').change(function() {
 const modules = {!! $modules !!};
$( "#moduleType-{{$module->id}}" ).change();
}

Comment: I also tried bit another code, but it works not how I expected it.
 <div id="moduleType-{{$module->id}}" style="display:none;">
<script>
    @foreach($modules as $module)
    $('#type').on('change',function(){
        $("#moduleType-{{$module->id}}").hide();
        var some = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
        $("#moduleType-" + some).show();
    });
    @endforeach
</script>

Comment: I've updated the answer. try it and tell me how it goes.

Comment: thanks for quick response! But still doesn't works. My code now: 
<select class="dropdownHeader function" id="type" name="type">
    @foreach($modules as $module)
        <option value="{{ $module->id }}">{{$module->name }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
<div id="moduleType" >
    <span id="status"">Database:</span>
    {!! Form::text('database',isset($module->DB)? $module->DB : old('DB'))!!}
    <span id="status">Path:</span>
    {!! Form::text('path',isset($module->path)? $module->path : old('PATH'))!!}
    <span  id="status">Friendly name:</span>
</div>

Comment: <script>
    $('#type').change(function() {
        const modules = {!! $modules !!};
        const type = this.val(); 
        const module = modules[type]; 
        $('#status').html(module.enabled);    }
</script>

maybe I miss something?